# SVN post-commit hook executing on client

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm attempting to add a post-commit hook to Subversion that will send an email to a group of users when a change is committed to the code base.

I have been following [these instructions](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/), however when I make a commit, the command appears to be executing on the client that made the commit, rather than the SVN server.

To test this, I have tried using the following command as a post-commit hook:

```
@echo %1 %2>C:\svnhooktest.txt
```

expecting a text file with the repository path and revision number to be created on the server's C: drive. However, the file is created on the client's C: drive, causing me to believe that the command is being run on the client.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, and how I can get the command running on the server?

Answer (score 0):

> I have been following these instructions, however when I make a
>   commit, the command appears to be executing on the client that made
>   the commit, rather than the SVN server.

If you did follow the instruction and put the code to the `post-commit.cmd` then the hook has to be working as expected.

I can advise to follow steps from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453718/761095) to analyze what the hook actually does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried what you said in the linked answer but unfortunately it was no help. The log just re-indicates that the script is running on the client, which is not the behaviour I am expecting.